# Python Flask app to output remote server text file to webserver using ajax and display on webpage getting 404 not found

Tags: python, ajax, linux, python-3.x, flask

I have a web server (fedora with apache) running my website and I'm currently trying to create my Flask app to receive AJAX calls from my `app.js` file and then ultimately using `FTP` to get the contents of a remote text file to output back to the website.

I am having a problem getting my routes to hit my Flask app when I make my AJAX calls. I believe I know what the problem is, my AJAX calls are not making the call to port 5000 that's why I see the 404 error in the console. However, when I manually do `curl -X GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/index -d'test'` I do see the correct `index.html` page being returned as expected.

So my questions is, how is Flask usually set up on an apache webserver?

Here is my AJAX call to Flask (app.py).

app.js:

```
$(function(){                // this call is returning 404 not found.
$('button').click(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/index',    
        data: user,
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(response){
            console.log("Here is the success res: " + response + user);
        },
        error: function(error){
            console.log("Here is the error res: " + error + user);
        }
    });
});
});
```

And here is where my Flask function routes my calls.

app.py:

```
from flask import Flask, request, send_file, render_template, json
from ftplib import FTP                                                                      

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'hello world!'

@app.route('/index', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

All the processes listening on port 80:

```
# lsof -i:80
COMMAND     PID   USER   FD   TYPE  DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
/opt/lamp  3179 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp  6833 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp  7665   root    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp  7909 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp  7919 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 10892 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 11676 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 11843 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 12345 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 12755 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
/opt/lamp 20204 daemon    4u  IPv6 2190211      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This page](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/) details your deployment options.

The big difference between Flask (and python applications in general), is that PHP is at its heart a templating system. Each PHP file is, to your web server, just an HTML file.  Remember that PHP is a hypertext processor by its own definition.

Python web applications, on the other hand, are applications that run on your server ready to handle requests and return html. Basically, you need to be able to on one hand, run the python application, and on the other hand, handle requests from the outside world and return webpages.

On your setup with Apache already installed and working, I would use the [mod_wsgi/Apache method](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/mod_wsgi/).  This uses the [Python Web Server Gateway Interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) to provide a bride between your running application and Apache.

You could also use [Gunicorn](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/deploying/wsgi-standalone/), but if you're already familiar with Apache, mod_wsgi is probably best.

It's worth noting that you should only deploy your application once you're done testing, as debug won't work in any forking environment (besides being a huge security risk if it could).  If your problem is the port for local testing, change:

```
app.run()
```

to:

```
app.run('localhost', port='80', debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation! The problem with setting the port to 80 is, I have other processes already listening to it, so when I try to force flask to run on port 80, it will complain `OSError: [Errno 98] Address already in use`. I'm not sure if it will be safe to kill all the http process, I guess I can try and see what happens. I edited my original post to show the processes listening on that port. Maybe you have a better solution?

Comment: Hey, sorry for the delayed response, but port 80 in my answer is arbitrary, you can still set it to any port that works.  It's also worth noting that sometimes flask doesn't release resources properly when killed on the command line, so this error can occasionally be fixed with "ps aux | grep python" then "kill [pid]"